# How do I pass in a vector of doubles to a constructor and then access its data in child classes (in C++)?

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, constructor

I want to be able to create not only a Chart, but a BarChart, and to pass in a vector of doubles and have that data put into the private member data.  How would I do this in the BarChart (child) class of Chart?  Also I am still confused as to pass by pointers, reference, or value, so I'm not sure if I am passing it correctly here.  Please let me know how to fix this mess.  Thank you for your help!

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class Chart
{
  public:
    Chart(vector<double> &d) : data(d) {}
    virtual void draw() const;
  protected:
    double value_at(int index) const; // ... only allows access, not modification
    int get_size() const
    {
      return data.size();
    }
  private:
    vector<double> &data; // Now data is safely private
};

class BarChart : public Chart
{
  public:
    virtual void draw() const
    {
      for (int x = 0; x < get_size() - 1; x++)
      {
        cout << value_at(x) << " ";
        for (int y = 0; y < value_at(x); y++)
        {
          cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
      }
    }
};

#include <iostream>
#include "chart.h"
#include <vector>    
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  vector<double> doubles;
  doubles.resize(4);
  for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
  {
    doubles[x] = x + 1.7;
  }
  BarChart c(doubles);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your data member is a reference, so you need to pass a reference.

Comment: Making `data` a reference is probably a pretty bad idea.

Comment: If you do not intend to change data, make it a const reference. But bear in mind that the onus is on you to ensure that the referenced data is not destroyed before the `Chart` object.  It would be more robust to have the Chart object own its data: either holding it by value, or by a `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want now. By the way you have to read these things for your future :)

1. How access modifiers works in inheritance
2. How constructors initialize in inheritance
3. What is the difference between pass by reference and pass by value.

These all you can read in the internet. Only thing is need to spend some time for find and read.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Chart
{
public:
    Chart(std::vector<double> &d) : data(d) {}
    virtual void draw(){}
    double value_at(int index) const{ return data[index];} 
    int get_size() const{return data.size();} 
private:
    std::vector<double> &data;
};

class BarChart : public Chart
{
public:
    BarChart(std::vector<double> &d):Chart(d)
    {
    }
    virtual void draw()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < get_size() - 1; x++)
        {
            std::cout << value_at(x) << " ";
            for (int y = 0; y < value_at(x); y++)
            {
                std::cout << "*";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> barchartData;
    barchartData.push_back(10);
    barchartData.push_back(20);
    BarChart barchart(barchartData);
    std::cout << "Barchart size :" << barchart.get_size() << std::endl;

    std::vector<double> chartData;
    chartData.push_back(500);
    chartData.push_back(600);
    Chart chart(chartData);
    std::cout << "Chart size :" << chart.get_size() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  It wasn't compiling at first, wasn't sure what the problem is.  But I got it working.  This works great.  There is one small logic issue - in the virtual void draw method of class BarChart, it should be x < get_size() without the - 1 since we mentioned "<" rather than "<=".  Just an off-by-one logic error on my part.